# Why Logger is singleton not static?

Tags: java, logging, design-patterns

I was reading some materials online for singleton vs static class. Some of them mentioned if the class doesn't maintain state, you should use static class not singleton. However, as far as I know, Logger class is singleton not static class. But I didn't see any state it actually maintain here. Am I wrong on it? Or anything I didn't see? Thanks in advance.

Comment: A logger API can maintain a lot of state, like the default level of the logging out put, the delegates through which the logging information is transformed and recorded, etc

Comment: The Java logger specifically has A LOT of state.  Each one of its output handlers is a separate class, and each of those has its own configuration.  Basically look at the logger configuration documentation and all of that is state that the API has to remember.

Comment: @MadProgrammer, thanks for ur answer. But will the things you brought up not be able to done by a static util method? For example, for the delegates, can I do something like get the class dynamically and use it in my static log method? I am sorry if it sounds dummy.

Comment: @Laodao But those things would then need to be maintained via `static` fields, which defeats the purpose, now you have `static` state and now we've ventured into another dangerous error. *"For example, for the delegates, can I do something like get the class dynamically and use it in my static log method?"* - But the delegates also maintain their own state

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot. Good point. @MadProgrammer

Comment: Where did you see that "Logger class is singleton"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically singleton is a design pattern, which by it's nature a static implementation.

- Singleton by it's definition only enforces that you can have only a single instance of the given object. This can be very useful when you want to compose functions into classes which can be reused from multiple places.
  Also in this case your singleton class can have a state, can be replaced, can be removed, recreated etc.
- When it comes to static you are limited to have one of them by the JVM, you cannot replace it easily, and as you mentioned, it is not advisable to assaign state to them (nevertheless there are ways to do that).

Generally speaking I don't like to introduce two singleton implementation into the same codebase, but usually the convention is to only use static if you implement some kind of library function like `add(a,b)`, and prefer using singletons for beans, business logic, etc.